# Laplace equation for three semi-infinite conducting planes at potential V meet at the right angle to form a cubic corner

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-equations

[image]

Let the planes be $x = 0$, $y = 0$ and $z = 0$ and they all have the same potential $V_0$. the question is to find the potential in the region $x > 0$, $y > 0$ and $z > 0$.

I know that from the separation of variables, we can assume that potential function is given by:
\begin{align}
V(x, y, z) = X(x) Y(y) Z(z)
\end{align}
which changes the Laplace equation to:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{X}\frac{d^2X}{dx^2} + \frac{1}{Y}\frac{d^2Y}{dy^2} + \frac{1}{Z}\frac{d^2Z}{dz^2} = 0
\end{align}

normally the the Laplace equation will be separated in three equations:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{X}\frac{d^2X}{dx^2} = -\alpha^2 \rightarrow X = A e^{-j\alpha x} + B e^{j\alpha x}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{Y}\frac{d^2Y}{dy^2} = -\beta^2 \rightarrow Y = C e^{-j\beta y} + D e^{j\beta y}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{Z}\frac{d^2Z}{dz^2} = \gamma^2 = \alpha^2 + \beta^2 \rightarrow Z = E e^{-\gamma z} + F e^{\gamma z}
\end{align}

But in this problem, because of the boundary conditions, there are no periodic answers for any of the separated functions. therefore I think the Laplace equation would result in:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{X}\frac{d^2X}{dx^2} = 0 \rightarrow X = A x + B
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{Y}\frac{d^2Y}{dy^2} = 0 \rightarrow Y = C y + D
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{Z}\frac{d^2Z}{dz^2} = 0 \rightarrow Z = E z + F
\end{align}

But I have a problem with placing the boundary conditions in the equation. Because there are three boundary conditions $X(\infty) = 0$, $Y(\infty) = 0$, and $Z(\infty) = 0$ that when I try to place them in the proper equations, I can't find the constants. How can I use the Boundary conditions to find the answer?

Comment: I think the solution you are seeking is just $V=V_0$, unless you make the walls finite in extent. $V = 0$ at infinity is not a viable boundary condition in this case, since the conductors have non-zero potential and extend to infinity. An infinite conducting sheet of potential $V_0$ at $x=0$ is a simpler 1D problem that illustrates the same issue: there is no potential solution that simulataneously satisfies $V(0) = V_0$ and $V(\infty) = 0$, unless $V_0 = 0$.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I think you're right that this problem is not applicable. if we multiply the functions based on the Laplace equation, the result is: $V(x, y, z) = Ax + By + Cz + Dxy + Exz + Fyz + Gxyz + H$ and by placing the hypothetical boundary conditions, the answer is: $V(x, y, z) = H = V_0$